Error 500 while deploying Prisma on Vercel
I am deploying my build on Vercel. It is working fine locally but when I build it on Vercel, I am getting an error when I try to access my database through Prisma:
"Request failed with status code 500"

Below you'll see my API route.ts file :
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


export async function POST (req : Request, ) 
{
    try 
    {
        const { email } = await req.json();
        const contact = await db.contact.create({data: {email}})
        return NextResponse.json(contact);
    } 

    catch (error) 
    {
        if (error instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) 
        {
            console.log("[CONTACT]", "Email déjà existant");
            return NextResponse.json({message: "Email déjà existant" }, {status : 520});
        }
        else { 
            console.log("[CONTACT]", error);
            return NextResponse.json({message: "Erreur de serveur" }, {status : 500});
        }
    }
}

Below you'll see my db.ts file :
// In Pre-Production ⬇️

/* 
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
declare global {var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;};
export const db = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prisma = db;
*/

// In production ⬇️

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
export const db = new PrismaClient();

// Prisma Studio
// >>> npx prisma studio

I also include my schema.prisma file :
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider      = "cockroachdb"
  url           = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode  = "prisma"
}

model Contact {
  email     String   @id @unique
  creation  DateTime @default(now())
}

To solve this issue, here is what I've tried so far :

I updated my code in db.ts file by adding the "production" part (which didn't work)
In the package.json file I added a postinstall command whithin the script section

"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  }

Any idea on how to solve this issue?
